# Showing a field mod a prime polynomial is a field

Tags: galois-theory

If I have a field $\mathbb{F}$ and an irreducible polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ will $\mathbb{B}= \mathbb{F}[x]/p(x)$ be a field, why?

Comment: Well, what do you think about the problem? This is a standard result in literally any book that covers, say, introductory ring theory.

Comment: I figure it would be, I should read a book to see a proof.

Comment: What do you know about the quotients of a ring by special ideals ? (prime ideals, maximal ideals, etc.)

Comment: $\mathbb{F}$ is an Euclidean domain so $\mathbb{F}[X]$ is a PID. We know that the ideal $(p(X))$ has to be a maximal ideal because if $(p(X))\subset I$, then $I=(q(x))$ for some $q(X)\in\mathbb{F}[X]$ and that tells us that $q(X)$ divides $p(X)$. If we quotient out by a maximal ideal, we get a field.